# Is it possible to make a mosaic heatmap in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, heatmap, mosaic-plot

Is there a way in matplotlib to generate a heatmap with white space between blocks that I define. For example, I have a 100x100 matrix. I define 4 blocks as follows

block1 = mat[0:50,0:50]

block2 = mat[0:25,50:100]

block3 = mat[25:100,50:100]

block4 = mat[50:100,0:50]

I want to plot a heatmap such that the blocks are separated by a white space. Can this even be done? If not in matplotlib, how about some other tool like ggplot2?